# How to read data from data bag within a PIG script

Tags: apache-pig

I have a databag which is the following format
`{([ChannelName#{ (bigXML,[])}   ])}`

- DataBag consists of only one item which is a Tuple.
- Tuple consists of only item that is Map.
- Map is of type  which is a map between channel names and values.
- Here is value is of type DataBag, which consists of only one tuple.
- The tuple consists of two items one is a charrarray (very big string) and other is a map

I have a UDF that emits the above bag.

Now i need to invoke another UDF by passing the only tuple within the DataBag against a given Channel from the Map.

Assuming there was not data bag and a tuple as
`([ChannelName#{ (bigXML,[])}   ])`
I can access the data using `$0.$0#'StdOutChannel'`
Now with the tuple inside a bag
`{([ChannelName#{ (bigXML,[])}   ])}` 
If i do `$0.$0.$0#'StdOutChannel'`  (Prepend $0), i get the following error
 `ERROR 1052: Cannot cast bag with schema bag({bytearray}) to map`

How can I access data within a data bag?

Answer (score 2):

Try to break this problem down a little.

Let's say you get your inner bag:

```
MYBAG = $0.$0#'StdOutChannel';
```

First, can you `ILLUSTRATE` or `DUMP` this?

What can you do with this bag? Usually `FOREACH` over the tuples inside.

```
A = FOREACH MYBAG {
    GENERATE $0 AS MyCharArray, $1 AS MyMap
};

ILLUSTRATE A; -- or if this doesn't work
DUMP A;
```

Can you try this interactively and maybe edit your question a little more with some details as a result of you trying these things.

Some editing hints for StackOverflow:

- put backticks around your code (`ILLUSTRATE`)
- indent code blocks by 4 spaces on each line